# Python script throwing very odd error when trying to open a text file

Tags: javascript, python, html, xmlhttprequest, cgi

First off, I am a total beginner when it comes to web tech, so this may be a relatively simple problem to solve. I am attempting to open a text file from a python script that is interacting with an XMLHTTPRequest and I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ryan/VirtualDesktop/ComputerScience/4410_web_Technologies/projects/p3stuff/cgi-bin/p3.py", line 20, in <module>
msgs = open("msgs.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'msgs.txt'
```

This is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
sys.stderr = sys.stdout

print("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

msgs = open("msgs.txt")
print(msgs.read())
```

The "msgs.txt" file is definitely in the proper directory and it runs fine if I run the python script in my terminal (without interacting with the javascript):

```
ryan@ryan-XPS-15-9560:~/VirtualDesktop/ComputerScience/4410_web_Technologies/projects/p3stuff/cgi-bin$ ls
msgs.txt  p3.py*
ryan@ryan-XPS-15-9560:~/VirtualDesktop/ComputerScience/4410_web_Technologies/projects/p3stuff/cgi-bin$ ./p3.py 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-type: text/html

alice: hello
bob: whatever

ryan@ryan-XPS-15-9560:~/VirtualDesktop/ComputerScience/4410_web_Technologies/projects/p3stuff/cgi-bin$
```

It seems to me the javascript code that I am using to interact with the python script is working fine, as it goes smoothly if I just print the contents of `msgs.txt` straight from the python file (ie removing the last two lines of the python code and replacing them with `print("alice: hello\nbob: whatever")`. Just trying to access that file seems to be my main problem. It's like the python script can't even see it when I'm trying to open it from my webpage.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Using the full filepath in the `open` call is not permitted (this is  part of an assignment).

Comment: Have you considered that the "*proper directory*" (most likely your **home directory** (*Python*: `os.getcwd()`)), might change under some circumstances (e.g. when running from an outside tool)? What happens if you specify the full path?

Comment: try to add the full path of the file. For example; open("c:\folder\msgs.txt")

Comment: The way that open() is being used is referring to a relative path. If you execute p3.py from anywhere outside of that directory, you're going to run into an error.

Comment: If `"msgs.txt" in os.listdir(os.getcwd())` is not `True`, either change your working directory to where the file is (using `os.chdir(...)`) or specify the full path, just like anonyXmous mentioned.

Comment: Adding the full path does work! And I thank you all for the suggestion. The only problem I now face is that this is a project for a class and we were specifically told not to use the full file path because our professor will be running it on his local machine when we turn it in and it is guaranteed that our file paths will be different. Is there a quick way to get the full file path at runtime and use that by chance?

Comment: Check my 1st comment, maybe you'll find smth useful there.

Comment: Thank you. Reading that just showed me the light lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `msgs.txt` will be in the same directory as `p3.py`, you can query the directory portion of `__file__`.

Try this:

```
import os

def filename(x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), x)

with open(filename('msgs.txt')) as msgs:
    print(msgs.read())
```

Comment: Shout out to you. Thank you very much, that did precisely what I needed.